# Does RandomForest ignore spatial independence?

Tags: random-forest, spatial, independence

I have 5 variables for each countries of the world and I need to analyze their effect and interactions on an independent variable.
Random Forest would be adequate for my scope as it deals with non-linear relationships and predicts variables importance. However, I'm wondering if spatial dependence may be an issue. I've never seen spatial dependence discussed in RF applications even if it has been widely used for spatial data.

Comment: Some related discussion: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502459/how-to-include-the-effect-of-the-spatial-autocorrelation-in-random-forest-algori

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has no problem with spatial autocorrelation of your response or explanatory variables. It's a totally non-parametric technique. I have used it for the interpolation of structural diversity variables across my country based on in situ data from a regular grid and introducing the coordinates as covariables even produces better predictions. This is because Random Forest is based on a divide and conquer approach (classification and regression trees), meaning it separates your feature space into disjoint subsets where simpler models (by default a simple average in the case of regression) can produce good predictions. Introducing the coordinates as variables, in my case, exploits spatial autocorrelation as it makes sense that certain geographic subsets of the country behave homogeneously.

Comment: While I tend to agree with the answer, are you aware of any empirical studies that show this to be the case? RF definitely has issues wrt importance scores and highly correlated variables (e.g., [Strobl et al](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/9/307)).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense since when you grow a tree, at each split, it must be decided what variable it's going to use. In the extreme case, if you have two perfectly correlated variables the splitting scheme would simply choose one of them randomly. Thus if you re-train the random forest you would see the importance scores being very unstable in these correlated variables. They would be very prone to switch places in the hierarchy.

Comment: @JEquihua I know I am very late to the party but I'd be very interested to know how you incorporated coordinates as covariables? I am using the randomForest package in R and am not aware of any options to include covariables yet it makes a lot of sense especially with clustered spatially autocorrelated data.

Comment: Hello @Kristina. I just introduced them as additional features, i.e. lat and lon as two different columns in your train table. This only works if your train data represents well your geographical space, in my example I had around 25,000 points located on a regular grid over my area of interest.

Comment: @JEquihua Thanks for your response! I tried this before, however, I had the impression that this heavily skewed the model. However, this might be due to the fact that I have several independent regions (marine protected areas across the globe) in my data. Do you have any suggestions how best to handle this as I'd very much like to include location. Thank you!

Comment: @Kristina, one thing that comes to mind, although you have probably tried it already, is to introduce a categorical variable that indicates the regions. Another thing, although it would require a lot more time and mind investment would be to try and do some unsupervised feature learning on the features you already have, I imagine that for all the world so you can introduce coordinates as features for this. Look for: Learning Feature Representations with K-means by Adam Coates and Andrew Y. Ng. That applied to spatial data will usually find autocorrelated behaviours in your features.

Comment: @JEquihua Thanks, I did try the categorical variable and I think I'll just stick with it, but very good to hear that this is a good option and thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: @Kristina with fear of stating something silly, you could also try introducing both. The coordinates AND the categorical variable for regions. Random Forest usually is quite good at finding interactions between variables so maybe it will discover it can first split by region and then use the coordinates inside those splits (by region). That would be interesting. Although for it to work you would probably have to have a nice distribution of points per region. There are even things already developed to study these interactions using R, I think in the randomForestSRC package.